# Find total count based of values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql:

I have cities in table with duplicate values:

Table Cities:

```
Name

New York, USA
New York, USA
Chicago, USA
Chicago, USA
Chicago, USA
Paris, France
Nice, France
Milan, Italy
```

The format of data in this table is:

```
<city>, <country>
```

Same as:

```
<city><comma><space><country>
```

Table Country:

```
Name

USA
France
Italy
```

I want to get how many cities each country has. Like:

```
Country      Count

USA           2
France        2
Italy         1
```

So, I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `Cities` WHERE Cities.name LIKE '%, USA%'
```

But this value `USA` should come from:

```
SELECT * FROM `country`
```

Now, how do I get the desired table?

Comment: Note that as far as 'relational' data is concerned, if you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table.

Comment: Agreed. The table Cities has a primary key but not on the cities column. This is just a small portion of database that I wanted the query on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.name Country, count(distinct t2.name) Count
from country t1 left join cities t2 
on t2.name like concat('%, ', t1.name)
group by t1.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r9nt19aSw2APCkVfBLz86B/3).
Results:

```
| Country | Count |
| ------- | ----- |
| France  | 2     |
| Italy   | 1     |
| USA     | 2     |
```

Comment: thanks, I am trying it now. I thought it will be a nested query.

Comment: It worked fine. However, one issues is that I forgot to mention that cities in table have duplicate values. I have updated the sample data. I think I have to use DISTINCT or UNIQUE somewhere in the query?

Comment: It worked perfectly! You saved 5-6 hours of my time today.